# Week start from Sunday while calculating weekday

Tags: sql, oracle, nls-lang

I am trying to find the weekday for Sunday to Saturday. In oracle by default Monday is the first day of the week. So When I calculate weekday with following query

```
Select    to_char(sysdate, 'D')  from dual
```

as today is 09/12/2022 this is giving me result as `5` as week start from Monday. I want this should be calculated as week start from Sunday. Ideally, answer should be `6` if this week start from Sunday.

Is there any easy way to do it, I can use case statement, but that is not a good way. Please help.

Comment: "In oracle by default Monday is the first day of the week." This is incorrect as the first day of the week depends on the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter which any user can change in their own session.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter

In Oracle, the day of the week depends on the `NLS_TERRITORY` session setting:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2022-12-11', 'D') AS day, -- a sunday
       (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TERRITORY')
         AS territory
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs different values for different parameters. I.e., if you use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='America';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='Germany';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='India';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='Oman';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='Bangladesh';
```

and run the query for each then the outputs are:

| DAY | TERRITORY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AMERICA |
| 7 | GERMANY |
| 1 | INDIA |
| 2 | OMAN |
| 3 | BANGLADESH |

So you could just pick the correct territory for your database, i.e.:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='India';
```

---

#### Option 2: Compare to the start of the ISO-week

Or if you want to be independent of the session settings then you can compare it to the start of the ISO-week (which is always midnight Monday) and offset by one day to change the comparison from Monday-Sunday to Sunday-Saturday:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1) - TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') + 1 AS day
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which, for today (Friday) outputs:

| DAY |
| --- |
| 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cpoMR70h)

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your DBA to fix territory. If it was set to e.g. India, then you wouldn't have to *calculate* anything:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_territory = 'India';

Session altered.

SQL> Select    to_char(sysdate, 'D') from dual;

T
-
6

SQL>
```

Comment: what if sysdate is sunday this will give me 8, in that case it should show 1

Comment: True; that was a stupid suggestion. Fix the territory (or use CASE, but that's something you'd want to avoid anyway).

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, the first day of a week is determined by [`NLS_TERRITORY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html#GUID-4EB27E18-0A46-4380-A3EE-031BC19BAC20) parameter. So use [a value of `NLS_TERRITORY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/appendix-A-locale-data.html#GUID-550D6A25-DB53-4911-9419-8065A73FFB06) where Sunday is the first weekday, for example, `AMERICA`.

```
alter session set nls_territory=RUSSIA
```

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'D')
from dual
```

| TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D') |
| --- |
| 5 |

```
alter session set nls_territory=AMERICA
```

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'D')
from dual
```

| TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D') |
| --- |
| 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KnqsIUXc)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this, which is dead easy

```
select mod(to_char(sysdate,'D'),7)+1 as Weekday from Dual
```

Comment: As commented in the question, this is **not default** value, but `NLS_TERRITORY` specific. This code will produce different result depending on this setting. You may experiment using, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74742762/2778710).